# How Do I Run PHP Script with parameters in URL with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a noob to development and I am trying to figure out out how to run my own basic php using AWS Elastic beanstalk.  I followed the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.Walkthrough.html) and was able to successfully deploy and run the php-secondsample script that was provided.  However, when I created a new application with my own script the page returns blank. I am passing the URL "http://myenvironment.elasticbeanstalk.com/myfunction.php?action=test"  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my script called index.php

```
 <?php


    $action = $_GET['action'];
    if($action == "") $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    myconnect();

    if($action == 'test'){
      echo "Success!";
    }

     function myconnect(){


     define('DB_SERVER', 'redacted');
     define('DB_USERNAME', 'redacted');
     define('DB_PASSWORD', 'redacted');
     define('DB_DATABASE', 'redacted');

     $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
     //$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());


    if (!$connection) { 
       echo( "<p>Unable to connect to the " . 
          "database server at this time.</p>"
     ); 
      exit(); 
     }
    // Select the database 
    if (!mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) ) {
     echo( "<p>Unable to locate the medical " . 
          "database at this time.</p>" ); 
      exit(); 
     }
    }



?>
```

Comment: Where have you defined the `myconnect()` function?  If it is not defined you will get fatal error (and blank page).

Comment: Can you look at your logs? You can get logs using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: @MikeBrant please check my edit. i added my myconnect function.  thanks

Comment: @DollaBill would you still be able to provide some logs so we can see what is failing?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do with the following code ?

```
1) if($action == "") $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
2) $type = $_GET['type'];
```

If you are using only GET at this time, you can simply avoid the 1.
$_REQUEST Super global will return an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

If you are passing 'type' as an optional GET parameter, you can use something like this

```
$type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : '';
```

Rest of your code seems to be fine.